# USB Device active in Safe-Mode with Command Prompt(XP)

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, safe-mode

I have come across mixed answers for this so I would like to set the record straight.
This poor PC is damaged beyond repair and the only attempt at recovery is by booting in safe mode with command prompt.

The computer is running windows XP.

Will it be able to load a USB device in order to transfer files while in safe mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry the answer is no: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310496

What makes you say it is damaged beyond repair? I may be able to guide you. Do you you have the install media? What service pack is the install media, and what service pack is the damaged install?

Comment: I mean it wont boot(not even in safe mode), and before formatting everything I was going to attempt to pull some files. (possibly a HD issue but was going to attempt to pull what i could.

Comment: Ok, you can do a number of things: You can pull the drive, and put it into a desktop computer, or even the housing for an external drive (do this for an external you don't care about...it is not hard, and not easy to damage, but just in case). In the alternative, you can repair your Windows. Follow my instructions here: http://superuser.com/questions/295412/switching-motherboard-without-new-install/295449#295449

Comment: That was my second option. I was trying to get some options before I headed out. Its a family members computer so I didnt want to have to pull their drive/bring my desktop with me.

Thanks for the tips and the link.

Comment: Good luck Harper.

Answer (score 0):

This question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/195817) —
you really *want* to rescue files from a dying computer (X),
but rather than ask how to do that,
you’ve chosen a *way* that you believe you can use
(Y = boot into safe mode and copy to a USB device),
and you’ve *asked* about that.

In addition to the options suggested in [the comments](https://superuser.com/q/297573/150988#comment313662_297650)
under the other answer, you could use a Linux boot device —
USB (pen drive) or DVD — to go into Linux live mode
and then copy the files to another USB drive or SD card.

Comment: As mentioned in the link in the accepted answer, a USB drive (Linux or otherwise), will work only if the BIOS supports it, which wasn't necessarily the case on those computers.  The OP isn't really clear about whether it boots in safe mode at all (the question and comment on the accepted answer seem to conflict).  So just to manage expectations, if it does boot in safe mode, a DVD might be the only way to accomplish your suggestion.  For readers unfamiliar with Linux, it would be helpful if you could expand your answer to describe how to copy the files off the drive when they boot into Linux.