# I'm changing motherboards, do I need to reinstall windows?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which steps are needed to change motherboard on Windows 7 without reinstalling?](https://superuser.com/questions/125323/which-steps-are-needed-to-change-motherboard-on-windows-7-without-reinstalling)
>   [Switching motherboard without new install?](https://superuser.com/questions/295412/switching-motherboard-without-new-install)

I currently have a:

```
Gigabyte GA-880GM-UD2H microATX (Socket AM3) DDR3
HD 5770 PCIE graphics card
```

And am getting a:

```
Gigabyte 990XA-UD3 AMD 990X (Socket AM3+) DDR3 Motherboard
2x6870 PCIE graphics cards to crossfire
```

I have Windows 7 ultimate on an SSD, will I simply be able to put it all together on the new motherboard without reinstalling Windows from fresh?

I have a lot of development software on my PC (such as IIS7.5 and SQL Server Express) which I really would rather NOT reinstall because it took so blooming long to tweak it to get it working in the first place!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which steps are needed to change motherboard on Windows 7 without reinstalling?](http://superuser.com/questions/125323/which-steps-are-needed-to-change-motherboard-on-windows-7-without-reinstalling) see also http://superuser.com/questions/295412/switching-motherboard-without-new-install

Comment: try this http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1488716

Answer (score 1):

No.  as long as you plug the SSD from your old motherboard to your new one, you should be fine.